# Failed to load resource file in Quarkus 3.0.3

Tags: quarkus

Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.0.3.Final:build (default) on project watcher-engine: Failed to build quarkus application: SRCFG00035: Failed to load resource file

The Quarkus application is loading a resource file during the build process.

```
quarkus:

  config:
    locations: file:///somepath
```

Comment: Are you sure the file exists, is readable, and the path is correct? Do you have the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: expecting to read this file during runtime not at compile time

Comment: Contents of `application.properties` and `application.yml` are read during build time, so specifying `quarkus.config.locations` in there means that Quarkus will attempt to read those locations during build. If you need to provide some runtime config values when you're actually running the application, you have to add that via a system property, like `java -Dquarkus.config.locations=file:///somepath -jar quarkus-run.jar`. Note that not all properties can be overridden this way, because some of them are evaluated during build, and changing them at runtime has no effect.